# Generic type parameter to set a List of a dynamic Type on runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I have a dynamic `Type` that is generated at runtime, say `myGeneratedType`. I'm trying to create an instance of the following class, where `T` should be `myGeneratedType`. I have come across several answers where a dynamic type had to be set to a property of a class, but cannot seem to get it to work on a `List<T>`:

```
Type myGeneratedType;

private class Container<T>
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public List<T> c { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    Container<myGeneratedType> c = new Container<myGeneratedType>(); 
}
```

Obviously, the line of code in my method `Main()` does not work. What should I do to create a class of `Container` with my dynamic type as the generic type parameter?

Comment: What other answers did you come across and why didn't they work?

Comment: Use MakeGenericType: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you add some context like what you are going to do with `c`? If you don't know that type at compile time you may construct the `Type` like @YairHalberstadt suggests, but that won't help to declare `c` and use it. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RenéVogt I am trying to deserialize different `JSON` messages, the container is always the same, however the data (`List<T>`) is not. At runtime I do have metadata on the definition of `T`, which I use to generate `myGeneratedType`. At the end, I would like to be able to deserialize this like `(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer())
                .Deserialize(json, typeof(Container<>).MakeGenericType(myGeneratedType))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MakeGenericType:

```
        var type = typeof(Container<>);
        var MyGenericType = type.MakeGenericType(myGeneratedType));
```

where `myGeneratedType` is a `Type`

Comment: `typeof(Container<>)` results in `null` for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Aquillo you're surely doing something wrong, `typeof(Container<>)` cannot return `null`.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: `myGeneratedType`  is of type `Type` - the `Type` instance describing the type. So it has to be `type.MakeGenericType(myGeneratedType)`. Your code results in a `Type` instance representing `Container<Type>`.

Comment: @RenéVogt @YairHalberstadt It does work, In debug my watch on `typeof(Container<>).MakeGenericType(myGeneratedType)` resulted in message `'typeof(Container<>)' is null`. However, testing this at runtime (followed by both your comments) it does work. Thanks!